# Django form.save() error

Tags: django, forms

my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme)

class Theme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text_color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

my form:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'start', 'end']

    theme = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Theme.objects.filter(public=True),
        empty_label='None'
    )
```

my view:

```
@login_required
    def index(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = EventForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
```

Now If I fill in the values in the form star, end, title and select a theme from a list that django creates for me I get an error when I try to run the form.save() method.

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "theme_id" violates not-null constraint
```

But when I look into form.cleaned_data I can see that in theme is an instance of my Theme model available.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to include `theme` in your `fields`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have commented but I don't have enough point.
I think better way to achieve this thing is:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'start', 'end', 'theme']
```

As 'theme' is foreign key to Event Model, it'll appear as drop down on your template.
As here you want to filter theme objects, you can achieve it by overriding **init** :

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['theme'].queryset = self.fields['theme'].queryset.filter(public=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'start', 'end', 'theme']
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot save `Event` without `Theme` object, so you need something like

```
form = EventForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # get your Theme object 'your_theme_object'
    event = form.save(commit=False)
    event.theme = your_theme_object
    event.save()
```

Comment: I know. But why can't I use form.save()? I mean the theme-object is already available in the form-object. This is the output of cleaned_data: {'start': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Prague' CET+1:00:00 STD>), 'theme': <Theme: Update>, 'end': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Prague' CET+1:00:00 STD>), 'title': u'Test'}